# 'if/else' vs 'if' for performance and readability?

Tags: javascript

I've recently started using Snippet 2 instead of Snippet 1, for basic selection statements.  This seems a bit un-conventional, so I wanted to know if there is performance difference, or if one seems more readable than the other.

**Snippet 1**

```
function foo() {
    if(case1){
        //...
    } else if (case2) {
        //...
    } else if (case3) {
        //...
    } else{
        // catch other cases
    }
}
```

**Snippet 2**

```
function foo() {
    if(case1){
        //...
        return;
    }
    if(case2){
        //...
        return;
    }
    if(case3){
        //...
        return;
    }
    // catch other cases
}
```

Comment: They will differ quite much in the "compiled" code.

Comment: You can test the performance yourself: http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: Personal preference: Snippet 2 to check preconditions and "bail out early". Snippet 1 to handle main functionality of the method in logically distinct cases (though I'd try to find a way to refactor it soon afterwards).

Comment: It's going to always depend on the real code. If your code has a pattern which clearly guarantees that each block will return out of the function, then the `else` is redundant, and I think can be eliminated without loss of readability. If the blocks are large, and it's not clear each block is guaranteed to return (even if they really do), then the `else` makes it more clear that you'll never be in two blocks, without digging through each block. So like most style things, it really depends on the situation.

Comment: amazed how many people aren't reading or interpreting this code correctly.

Comment: *"or if one seems more readable than the other."* Subjective question?

Comment: @FelixKling it's not _entirely_ subjective - many coding standards prohibit "early exit" from functions.

Comment: i like return as a flow, but some coding styles would abhor having more than one return per function...

Comment: `if-elseif-else` tells for first look than only one condition can happen, rewrite it by `if`s and returns *is* possible, but it would be like rewrite `for` with `while` cycle or `for-each` with simple `for`.

Comment: Because I'm surprised the word isn't there yet: the second is called the [Guard pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause).

Comment: @FlorianMargaine it's normally only called that though if the conditions and code blocks are relatively short compared to the bulk of the function.  FWIW, if I was writing code like this I'd ensure there's whitespace between every `if` block, and also before every `return`, to make it _completely obvious_ that every block ends in function termination.

Comment: @Alnitak - I'm curious as to which coding standard you speak of, can you provide a reference?

Comment: @pure_code.mom not one I've got, but I've _heard of_ such corporate coding standards that require that each function has exactly _one_ exit point.

Comment: ...I'm not asking if you have one...I'm asking if you can give me info. so I can look it up, I'm not disputing what you remember, I'm just asking for a reference.

Answer (score 3):

**Your snippets are the same thing**. But I'd use `elseif` even if I return. It kind of gives me a sense that those `if` statements are related and helps me with readability.

`if ... else` also helps in performance, let's say, when you're `if`-ing the same variable. Why test a condition if the previous one succeeded? `elseif` it so it won't try again.

**It's a matter of design.** *It depends on what you want to achieve so there's no EXACT BEST way of doing it. It's all a matter of how you need to exit your code block that contains the `if`s.*

Comment: @sircapsalot: What's the difference?

Comment: +1 because they are the same thing

Comment: @sircapsalot the return statements were apparently there all along, but I did not see them at first either. They threw off my answer a little bit as well - tried to rectify as best as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `If`s alone mean that all of the conditions can possibly happen - they'll be checked one by one. The chained `if-else` statements mean that only one of the conditions can actually happen - if one of the conditions get executed, I believe it skips over all of the rest. Most languages support a `switch` statement as well, which would be somewhat more readable than chaining together a bunch of `if-else-if` statements. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this applies in every language I've used so far.

Edit: In this particular case (as pointed out by some others below - thank you), all of the conditions cannot happen because of the `return` statements in each of the `if` statements. In a more general case though, my explanation still holds.

Comment: no, you're wrong. there's a `return` in each block, so they cannot _all_ happen.

Comment: how the helsinki did I miss those return statements? my brain entirely skipped over them haha

Comment: @pure_code.mom the log doesn't record individual edits made within 5 minutes of each other.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner there is no "general case" - the `return` statements make a massive difference to the semantic intent of the code.

Comment: @Alnitak Correct, they do. But when I say general case, I mean if(){} if(){} ....   vs. if(){} else-if {} else-if{} etc. I meant not including the actual content of what is inside the statements, but rather what comprises the statements themselves. I realized that that didn't actually fully answer the question, hence my edit. I still don't see the problem.

Comment: @sircapsalot i am keep viewing this question from beginning and the return statement is from the time of question creation

Comment: the problem is that your caveat only appears at the end of your answer, by which point you've already lost the argument

Comment: @Ankit i know - that's why i deleted my previous comment, and commented again :)  pure_code.mom is right.. this question did spawn quite a bit of stupid.. even from me haha

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs. As a general rule, the more exit points you have to a function, the harder it is to read. That said, there is often benefit of

```
if(somehting)
{
    // one liner;
    return;
}
if(something else)
{
    // 30 lines of something else.
    return;
}
// catchall
```

instead of:

```
if(something)
{
    // one liner;
    return;
}
else if(something else)
{
    // now nested! 30 lines.
    return;
}
```

Chances are, though, that you could probably make things *even easier* to read by turning those conditions into their own functions. Wouldn't this be nice:

```
if(something)
{
    doSomething();
}
else if(something else)
{
    doSomethingElse();
}
else
{
    doJustElse();
}
```

The benefit of the last one? Succinct, clear, clean, obvious, and a low learning curve.

Comment: downside of the last one?  No access to lexically scoped variables, unless they're passed as parameters.

Answer (score -1):

If you have too many `else if` statements then it always better to use `switch` rather than using `if`.

Comment: not part of the question.

Comment: i didn't understand why this answer is not part of the question.
[if-else-vs-switch](http://www.ashishpaliwal.com/blog/2009/08/if-else-vs-switch-%E2%80%93-which-is-better/)

Answer (score -1):

Snippet 1 is going to be better for performance when you don't need case 3 to be satisfied, since the other `else if` will not be fired.  However, if you have a lot of other `else if`, you should use a `switch`

Comment: neither fires more ifs than the other...

Comment: If the program needs to fire case 2, with Snippet 1, only the if and first else if will be tested. In snippet 2, all 3 ifs will be tested. Hence, Snippet 1 would be faster.  If case 3 needed to be tested, they would be equal.  Its a trivial increase, but still

Comment: Do you see the `return` statement in each `if` block?

Comment: Wow, i feel like such an idiot now...